# How to get the ASCII Char 20 Paragraph Symbol

Tags: .net, char, ascii

I have a Dictionary Byte, Char  ASCIIlist that I want to populate with the Oct (0-255) and symbol.

Then I bind ASCIIlist to a ComboBox.

My problem is the (char)20 shows nothing and I want the paragraph symbol.
How do I get the literal and not ASCII char as a control character?

If I put the char(20) in a DataTable and bind to the DataTable I do get the paragraph symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paragraph symbol (pilcrow) - ¶ is **not** ASCII 20. It is Unicode character hex 182.

ASCII character hex 20 is space.

There is no paragraph character in ASCII.

Comment: Why do you need such a list? It is entirely unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @BalamBalam - There is a bunch of characters in ASCII that are not printable. Why do you need them?

Comment: [Unicodedata.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) contains a list descriptions of of Unicode characters, one per line.  The file is 23697 lines long.  How many of them do you want in your list?

Comment: Boy was I confused.  You showed great restraint by not voting my question down.  What I learned is Char is Unicode (not ASCII).   What had thrown me off is Char(20) was displayed as paragraph in the DataTable as it did that for many non displayable character.

Comment: I just need a list of the first 256 characters.  I have a program to parse text files and the files can have various delimiters and want to allow the user to select the various delimiter from pull down.

Comment: @BalamBalam - Just have a list of the delimiters in a string. A string is implemented as a collection of characters (you can do `foreach Char c in aString`, for example). You can then convert to a bindable list.

Comment: But ¶ (pilcrow) is 182 in latin1

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant - Also.